# XDocument and reading xsi:nil="true" gives "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xml-nil

Happily reading XML with

```
var q2 = from c in xmlDoc.Descendants("Ticket")
         select new
                { Responded_Date = (DateTime)c.Element("Responded_Date") }
```

However when the tag is

```
<Responded_Date xsi:nil="true" />
```

I get "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime".  I don't wish to use the null coalescing operator but simply to take the null and insert into datatable

Answer (score 1):

Declare Responded_Date as a nullable datetime.

```
var q2 = from c in xmlDoc.Descendants("Ticket")
         select new { Responded_Date = (DateTime?)c.Element("Responded_Date") };
```

If the `<Responded_Date>` element is missing, a null value will be returned.

If it's an invalid date, you will get a **FormatException** - "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.". `<Responded_Date xsi:nil="true" />` will cause a FormatException.

Comment: How do I declare the datetime nullable inside the select new statement?

Comment: I get this error inside the select.  Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: Modifed the code snippet to clarify where to put the DateTime?.

Answer (score 0):

Linq to XML does not natively support `xsi:nil`, also see this [msdn social link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/7ae0a4e2-266d-4101-a6c2-8d82be517898/). As a workaround what you will have to do is manual checking and then either assign some default value for your date (i.e. `DateTime.MaxValue`) or use a class projection instead of an anonymous type and assign null to a nullable DateTime? property.

with anonymous type (`Responded_Date` of type `DateTime` :

```
 select new
          { 
            Responded_Date = c.Element("Responded_Date").Value!="" 
                             ? (DateTime)c.Element("Responded_Date")
                             : DateTime.MaxValue
          }
```

with custom class projection (`Responded_Date` of type `DateTime?`):

```
 select new MyFoo()
          { 
            Responded_Date = c.Element("Responded_Date").Value!="" 
                             ? (DateTime)c.Element("Responded_Date")
                             : null
          }
```